# How to create xml element containing CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need to create an xml from javascript where some xml element tag would contain simple string data while some will contain html data. for that i have created a function

```
function element(child, childValue) {
var element = document.createElementNS(url, child);
var elementText = document.createTextNode(childValue);
element.appendChild(elementText);
return element;
}
```

By calling abobe function this way "function(widgetData, widget1)". it creates below xml element.

```
"<widgetData>widget1<widgetData>"
```

Now i need to create xml tag containing html data for that calling above function following way

```
function(widgetData, '<p>hello, world </p>')
```

it creates below xml element

```
<widgetData>&lt;p&gt;Hello, world&lt;/p&gt;</widgetData>
```

I think we can do this by CDATA

```
<widgetData><![CDATA[<p>hello, world </p>]]></widgetData>
```

But don't know how to do it.

I tried

```
var elementText = document.CreateCDataSection(childValue);
```

but it is giving error "undefined function" in chrome .And in Firefox "Unsupported html document" error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [`.createCDATASection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createCDATASection)

The following should work:

```
function element(child, childValue) {
  var element = document.createElementNS(url, child);
  var section = document.createCDATASection(childValue);
  element.appendChild(section);
  return element;
}
```

Please note:

> This will only work with XML, not HTML documents (as HTML documents do not support CDATA sections); attempting it on an HTML document will throw NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR.

Comment: executing above code getting error "Failed to execute 'createCDATASection' on 'Document': This operation is not supported for HTML documents."

Comment: in firefox getting exception "[Exception... "Operation is not supported" code: "9" nsresult: "0x80530009 (NotSupportedError)" location: "<unknown>"]"

Comment: I quoted an important bit from the docs, which likely explains this error. In short, you'll have to use it with real XML documents.

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort.